# Attaching a vuex store from within a vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I'm having a situation where I use a specific Vue component in multiple ways. Sometimes I initialize it as an SPA with `new Vue({store})` and sometimes I use it from within another vue component.

E.g.

```
<template>
  <component/>
</template>
```

How would I go about attaching a vuex store to the component in the above situation? Manually overriding the $store property obviously does not work and the Vue instance itself doesn't really shed any light on the matter. Is there a way to achieve this?

I've written a simple store factory which creates a new instance of the vuex store but I need a way to attach this to a component from within a vue template/comp.

Said component is complex enough to warrant vuex.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently setting the $store property manually *does* do the trick.

```
this.$store = store
```

Comment: You could also look into store modules https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html and register a new module under a reserved namespace. While overriding vue's default store registration works in the component, you'll lose anything in your store that's not from your component's own store.

Comment: While  I'd generally agree. This doesn't fit my use case very well. I don't use global vuex stores but attach specific ones to groups of components. Overriding was a better solution in my case